# Custom Dialog buttons not calling their OnClick methods

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, android-alertdialog

I have a custom Dialog layout called `dialog_main.xml`

Inside that layout there two buttons. In my `MainActivity`, I defined two `OnClickListeners` and assigned them to my two buttons. However, when my `MainActivity` launches and my dialog appears, clicking on my buttons does nothing.

Also, as a side note `dialog.setCancelable(false);` doesn't seem to be working either. If I am not mistaken, that is supposed to prevent the dialog from closing when clicking outside of the dialog box?

The following is in my `MainActivity`:

```
        dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);
        dialog.setTitle("Checklist");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        final LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogButtonsView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_main, null);

        Button newChecklistButton = (Button) dialogButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.new_checklist_button);
        Button resumeChecklistButton = (Button) dialogButtonsView.findViewById(R.id.resume_checklist_button);

        newChecklistButton.setOnClickListener(newChecklistOnClickListener);
        resumeChecklistButton.setOnClickListener(resumeChecklistOnClickListener);




    private Button.OnClickListener newChecklistOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("called");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    private Button.OnClickListener resumeChecklistOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("called");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem is occurring because Button click listener is added to Button's using `dialogButtonsView` View object but it is not pass as Dialog View to `setContentView` method.Change :

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main);
```

to

```
dialog.setContentView(dialogButtonsView);
```

**EDIT:** 
Because creating Dialog object, no need to in `inflate` again which is passed in `setContentView` for accessing View's, just use `dialog` object to call `findViewById` method like:

```
Button newChecklistButton =(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.new_checklist_button);
```

Comment: Sweet and simple, thanks! I will accept this answer when it becomes available.